How to prevent environment variables from leaking into a CMake ExternalProject_Add?
In a CMake project, occasionally the need arises to configure another CMake project. This is usually done using ExternalProject_Add. There are two main reasons for doing this. One is building a separate package vendored into a project and the other is using a different toolchain. In the former case one has to be careful to forward CMAKE_C_COMPILER and other variables to the external project as the compiler typically should be the same. In the latter case, one typically omits these variables or explicitly specifies them to something else. However, environment variables (such as CFLAGS) are simply forwarded and the toolchain being called may not understand the compiler flags passed for the wrapping project. How to handle this situation correctly? Passing compiler flags via the environment is a very common thing to do. "Don't do that." is not a useful answer here. We do not magically change how people invoke CMake by wishful thinking. How should the ExternalProject_Add be parametrized such that a CFLAGS environment variable is not carried forward?

A method that happens to work, but is not necessarily an ideal solution is passing the flags explicitly to the ExternalProject_Add:
"-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=$ENV{CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD} $ENV{CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD}"
"-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=$ENV{CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD} $ENV{CPPFLAGS_FOR_BUILD}"

Please downvote this answer after providing better ones.
